# C# HTTPPost Response - Console App

Tags: c#, console-application

I am using an API to which I am making a Async call and that API has an option to return HTTPPost response (Sends the response back using HTTP Post).

Is it possible to run/execute a console app based on HTTP response?

The API I am using is a third party WCF service.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to write a C# application that makes an HTTP POST request and, when it receives the response, launches a console application.

You can launch a process using the [Process.Start Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx).